# Why is $U$ open if and only if $j^{-1}(U \cap A)= j^{-1}(U)$?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $(X, \tau)$ is a topological space and $A \subseteq X$. Suppose $A$ has the initial topology on $A$ with respect to the inclusion function $j: A \to X$.

Now suppose $U$ is open $X$ $\iff$ $j^{-1}(U)$ is open in   $A\iff j^{-1}(U \cap A)= j^{-1}(U)$ is open in $A$

Why we have the second equivalence? The set $U=U \cap A$ are not equal.. Has someone a solution to this question?

Comment: Hint: If $x\in U\setminus A$ then $j^{-1}(\{x\})=\emptyset.$

Comment: $U$ may be very well different from $A\cap U$ but their preimages can coincides

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$j^{-1}(U\cap A)=j^{-1}(U)\cap j^{-1}(A)=j^{-1}(U)\cap A=j^{-1}(U)$.

Comment: Where went the $A$ in the last part?

Comment: $j^{-1}(U)\subset A$ by definition of $j$